# Agora Analytics (BETA) Rest API does not work for route /analytics/call/lists route

Tags: analytics, agora.io

When making a GET request (through Postman) at "https://api.agora.io/beta/analytics/call/lists" with query parameters:

- appid (following the official documentation, i base64 encoded {Customer ID}:{Customer Secret} string)
- start_ts (timestamp format e.g. 1627990383)
- end_ts (timestamp format e.g. 1628163183)

[image]

When I make the request, i get a response with status 200 OK, but the response body is the following :

```json
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Unknown error"
}
```

I set the headers as mentioned in the official documentation :

[image]

Has anyone got a legit response from this request? And what was his request construction?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I asked the support what to do, this is what they answered me:

> The analytics restful API you are trying to use is part of the
> Enterprise support package and requires that for you to be able to use
> them. We do have something in the works for cheaper analytics later
> down on the line so if you do want to purchase a package for restful
> APIs for analytics, please let us know and we can put you in contact
> with a CSM.

I think this functionality is supported only in the Enterprise version of the package.